What was Ram's reasoning for not passing on his crown to one of his brothers, so he could be with Sita?
While Rama's duties as a husband are subordinate to his duties as a king, why didn't he pass on the mantle, I can think of some reasons, but is there any he gave?

It was his Father's wish. It was Bharata who was next in line. And he detested to take the crown and for himself. For him, Rama was everything. So there was no possibility that any of the brothers would accept such a thought. Let alone the public who wouldn't agree.

@SanatanaDhara is their any other direct dialogue on this?

His teacher's words, as he grew (which is missing in Valmiki Ramayana), your question directly co-relates to the "Making of Rama" for that you should reach Vasista Ramayana/Yoga. Good luck
